# RStudio keyboard shortcut to wrap / unwrap code in parentheses?

Tags: r, rstudio

Sometimes it's preferable to wrap commands in `(` and `)` so that the output prints to console

Random example:

```
(logical_sample <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0))
(sample_mean <- mean(logical_sample))
(sample_st_deviation <- sd(logical_sample)) 
(n <- length(logical_sample))
```

Is there a quick RStudio keyboard shortcut for un/parenthesising the same way we can use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to un/comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### According to the official list...

As you can see on the official **RStudio** `Keyboard Shortcuts` list ([link here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts)) there is none, but you can use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>P</kbd>  to jump to the matching parenthesising, which can help speed things up.

Hope this helps.